# How to take a recursive snapshot of a btrfs subvol?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, filesystems, btrfs

Assume that a btrfs subvol named "child-subvol" is within a another subvol say, "root-subvol" and if we take snapshot of "root-subvol" then, the "child-subvol" should also be taken a snapshot.

Since recursive snapshot support is not yet there in btrfs file system, how can this be achieved alternatively ?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Get all the residing  btrfs sub-volumes. Preferably in the sorted order as achieved by the command below.

$ btrfs subvolume list **--sort=-path** < top_subvol >

Step 2:
In the order of preference as obtained, perform delete/Snapshot operation.

$ btrfs subvolume delete < subvol-name >

Comment: This is a wrong answer, because the "snapshot" procedure is not atomic. It should not be called a snapshot. The correct answer is: There is (still) no way to take recursive snapshots on Btrfs. Only ZFS has a feature of that kind (zfs snapshot -r). Unlike Btrfs, ZFS has a subvolume hierarchy organized in a tree structure separated from the mounted directory structure (apart from optional default mount points). The subvolume tree represents recursive snapshot atomicity coverage, regardless mount points. https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zfs-snapshot.8.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering this too and haven't been able to find any recommended best practices online. It should be possible to write a script to create a snapshot that handles the recursion.

Comment: There is no way to write such a script without kernel-side support. A series of snapshots (without mutual atomicity) doesn't help. Let's assume that a program first creates a file in subvolume A and then writes a symlink to the new file into subvolume B. The wannabe-snapshotting script running around the same time could, for example, snapshot subvolume A first, _before_ the new file on A was created. Next it could snapshot subvolume B, _after_ the symlink from B to A was created. There. We have a dangling symlink between the two separate snapshots.

Comment: I'd say a non-atomic series of snapshots is better than failing to make any recursive snapshots at all though right?

Answer (score 0):

As Peter R suggests, you can write a script. However, if you want to send the subvolume it must be marked as readonly, and you can't snapshot recursively into readonly volumes.

To solve that you can use [btrfs-property](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property) (found through [this answear](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149933)) in the script that handles recursion, making it (after all snapshots are taken) mark the snapshots readonly, so you can send them.

Alternatively, you can do

```
cp -a --reflink=always /path/to/root_subvol/ /path/to/child_subvol/
```

(`--reflink=auto` never worked for me before, and could also help you catch errors)

It should be fast, and afaik with the same advantages as a snapshot, although you don't keep the old subvolume structure.

Comment: snapshot is atomic per subvolume, reflink is atomic per file.  Any program that uses multiple data files and modifies its data between the start and the end of a reflink copy may have its data corrupted (databases are particularly vulnerable to this.)