# send/receive subvolume with snapshots (btrfs)

Tags: docker, snapshot, btrfs

btrfs subvolumes are great, and can be nested. 
Docker has support for btrfs and makes heavy use of nested snapshots.

I'm trying to move my /var/lib/docker to a new drive.

The procedure "should" be.
1- make a ro snapshot of /var/lib/docker

```
btrfs sub snap create /var/lib/docker /var/snapshots/docker_some_datetime
```

both source and destination are on the same fs.

2.- send the snapshot to the new drive

```
btrfs send /var/snapshots/docker_some_datetime | btrfs receive /mnt/drive2/snapshots/
```

inside docker folder, there is a btrfs folder filled up with subvolumes. I expected that the folder inside the snapshot be subvolumes as well, but they appear to be just regular folders.

;TLDR
So, the question is, If I take a snapshot of a subvolume that has subvolumes nested inside, aren't they supposed to be subvolumes as well in the snapshot? Am I hitting a btrfs limitation here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take a recursive snapshot of a btrfs subvol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625712/how-to-take-a-recursive-snapshot-of-a-btrfs-subvol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think of BTRFS-Subvolumes as "normal" partitions for a second and look at an example:

- A partition of an HDD is mounted on `/mnt/hdd` and a second partition is mounted at `/mnt/hdd/nested`.
- If you take a full backup of the first partition (for example as `.img` or `.iso`), this will **not** include the second partition just because it is currently mounted "inside" the first partition.

Even if the first partition is **not mounted**, you can still take a backup of it.

As BTRFS-Subvolumes are handled similarly to partitions, a recursive btrfs-send (that includes currently "mounted" Subvolumes) is more complicated.

To my knowledge, there is no built-in function to do this with just one command.

I once digged through the BTRFS backup tools mentioned on the wiki and as far as I recall one of those tools has exactly that feature: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup#Available_Backup_Tools

---

Now for BTRFS (as far as I understand it):

- If you mount a BTRFS partition (e.g. via `/etc/fstab`), by default it's top-level Subvolume get's mounted at the desired location.
- And all Subvolumes residing inside the mounted BTRFS-Subvolume (by having a child-parent-relationship to the top-level Subvolume), get automatically "mounted" at a relative subpath as well.
- Though not all Subvolumes of one BTRFS-device must always be visible: If you use the mount option `subvolid=<ID-of-some-Subvolume>`, only child-Subvolumes are automatically "mounted" at a relative subpath.

(I put "mounted" several times in quotes as child Subvolumes get not *really* mounted - they're not visible as normal Linux mounts)

Answer (score 0):

Put short: no, nested subvolumes are not included in a snapshot of their parent but instead as you saw represented with an empty directory in the parent's snapshot, see the [BTRFS Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#When_To_Make_Subvolumes).

To snapshot a nested subvolume layout you must recursively snapshot all included subvolumes manually.